# nginx + php run with different user id

Tags: nginx, php

In the old, shared server system I was, my username as A. 
Each PHP script in my site was run with my own username:

```
$puser = posix_getpwuid(posix_geteuid())['name']; // = $puser = "A";
```

Now I run my own VPS which runs nginx and the username/group is nginx.

However I 've created a friend's account with username B and I want each PHP script he creates to execute with user B, not nginx. Basically I want each PHP script to be run with the UID of the same user that created it.

Is that possible with nginx ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With bare nginx, you cannot do it based on file ownership only.

PHP-FPM is the script execution engine that is used with nginx.

In PHP-FPM, there are PHP worker pools, which can be set up in different ports. Each PHP-FPM worker can have a user that is used to execute scripts for that pool.

Then, in nginx side, one configures rules which PHP-FPM backend is used for which request. The normal configuration is that each virtual host on nginx uses its own PHP-FPM worker pool.

With bare nginx, it is not possible to check file ownership so that backend location could be selected with that information. nginx `lua` module could be used for this purpose though.